# Homebrew Formula Syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, homebrew

I'm having much trouble understanding the syntax of a Homebrew Formula.

Let's have a look at this example:

```
require "formula"

class Foo < Formula
  url "http://example.com/foo-0.1.tar.gz"
  homepage ""
  sha1 "1234567890ABCDEF1234567890ABCDEF"

  # depends_on "cmake" => :build

  def install
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--disable-debug", "--disable-dependency-tracking"
#   system "cmake", ".", *std_cmake_args
    system "make install"
  end
end
```

What exactly does the following syntax means?

```
url "http://example.com/foo-0.1.tar.gz"
```

Is it some kind of a variable assignment? Construction of a url object?
I'm sorry but after passing over a whole Ruby tutorial, I still didn't understand it.

Also, please try to explain what this syntax is:

```
system "make install"
```

From what I have searched, Ruby doesn't have such method (or at least it doesn't call the system() method like this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find that these are calls to methods of the Formula class that Foo derives from (`Foo < Formula`). For example, the `system` method that's confusing you is just a method being called in Formula. Have a look in [`Formula.rb`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb) and you'll find most of your answers.

Homebrew is a complex program, with its functionality well-separated across different objects, as you'd expect. You may therefore need to trace some of the calls into other objects. For example, while `Formula` does have a `url` method, and that's what the `url` like you ask about is calling, you'll find that call is passed to a [SoftwareSpec](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb) object, which then stores it in a [Resource](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/resource.rb) instance variable as well as adding it to the dependency collector.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer! It's very surprising because inside the 
Cookbook formula "Coding style" it shows that method calls should be with parenthesis system("make install") vs system "make install".

Is it considered good coding style to write like this? What are things to be considered when choosing one style over the other.

I'm sorry I'm insisting but I would really like to understand this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about the Cookbook's coding style. General Ruby advice seems to be to favour parentheses on method calls (e.g. "...and precedence rules can make it difficult to know which argument goes with which method invocation, so we recommend using parentheses in all but the simplest cases."—Dave Thomas's *Programming Ruby*) but I've seen them omitted, especially in cases like Homebrew and Capistrano, where the "program" is meant to read more like a configuration file.

Comment: @cyberjoac, I think experienced rubyists like to show off and omit parentheses for method calls, but to my eye it makes code hard to read, so I use parenetheses...however, all rubyists write `puts 'hello'`, not `puts('hello')` and `p some_array` not `p(some_array)`. I also use python, and the switch from version 2.x to 3.x requires `print('hello')` instead of `print 'hello'`, and I absolutely can't stand having to write the parentheses in python 3.x, and I think that is a major flaw of python 3.x.

Comment: ...Ruby is also used for dsl's and lots of dsl's are designed to hide method calls by omitting parentheses in the syntax guide for the dsl.  Generally, I guess my rule is: if it's too irritating for me to type the parentheses then I omit them, otherwise I include them.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, please try to explain what this syntax is:
>
> ```
> system "make install"
> ```
>
> From what I have searched, Ruby doesn't have such method (or at least
>   it doesn't call the system() method like this).

Ruby does in fact have a system() method, and it is called exactly like that, see here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html

For instance, run this program:

```
system "ls *"
```

However, in ruby if a method does not have an explicit receiver, then ruby implicitly uses whatever object is `self` to call the method, i.e. self.system(...).

Inside a class, but outside any defs, self is the class:

```
class Dog
  p self  #=>Dog
end
```

And inside an instance method:

```
class Dog

  def bark
    p self
    puts 'woof'
  end

end

d = Dog.new
d.bark

--output:--
#<Dog:0x00000100a40280>
woof
```

self is the Dog instance that called the method, d in this case.  Those hieroglyphics are what ruby uses to denote a instance of a class.

Whenever you see a method call without an explicit receiver, such as

```
system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--disable-debug", "--disable-dependency-tracking"
```

it's good practice to say to yourself, `self.system(...) Which object is self?`  Your code boils down to this:

```
class Foo < Formula
  def install
    system(...)
  end
end
```

`self.system(..) Which object is self?`  self will be the instance of Foo that calls the install() method.  I would immediately assume that the system() call finds ruby's system() method--and the only way that wouldn't happen is if the Formula class defines a method named system(), and as Matt Gibson astutely checked, Formula does define a system() method.

```
What exactly does the following syntax means?

    url "http://example.com/foo-0.1.tar.gz"
```

Ruby translates that to:

```
self.url(""http://example.com/foo-0.1.tar.gz")
```